# Android - отслеживание доставки смс

Tags: android, sms

В моем приложении *смс* отправляются сервисом. Мне необходимо отслеживать, что *смс* отправлено и доставлено. [отслеживание и подтверждение доставки смс](http://src-code.net/otslezhivanie-i-podtverzhdenie%C2%A0-dostavki-sms/) - такой код не работает (работает только если смс отправляет activity).

Подскажите как отследить, что смс доставлено или нет, если оно отправляется сервисом?

Comment: Все отлично работает в сервисе. В чём проблема с сервисом?

Comment: Все отправляется, но не могу получить результат отправки. Сервис у меня работает не постоянно, а запускается, когда нужно отправить смс.

Comment: Тогда создайте отдельный сервис, который будет отслеживать отчет о прибытии, или в том же сервисе ждите отчета и не завершайте его. Или самое простое и правильное - создать отдельно broadcastreceiver и прописать его в манифесте. Все зависит от того, что вам нужно.

Comment: Я об этом думала. А что прописать в intent-filter и в самом классе в intent.getAction().equals?  "SENT_SMS_ACTION" и "DELIVERED_SMS_ACTION"?

Comment: Ну точно, так и сделала. Всё работает.